# The app size of given code is very large, is it because SDK?

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, voice, zegocloud

I have developed a simple voice calling app using zego Cloud in flutter for one to one voice calling. i want to use this feature in my app but the problem is that the app size of this feature is almost 80 mb. Why is it becoming so large? is it due to zego cloud sdk or something else? is their any way to reduce the app size. if not can you please suggest me another alternative for using using voice call with notification using flutter. given below is my code-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import'package:zego_uikit_prebuilt_call/zego_uikit_prebuilt_call.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;
final String userID=math.Random().nextInt(1000).toString();
void main() {

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home:  Audiocalling(),
    );
  }
}
class Audiocalling extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Audiocalling> createState() => _AudiocallingState();
}
class _AudiocallingState extends State<Audiocalling> {
  final _controller=TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("ZEGOCLOUD Audio Calling"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body:Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Enter UId"
              ),

            ),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder)=>cllingId(CallingId: _controller.text.toString())));
            }, child: Text("Join")),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
class cllingId extends StatelessWidget {
  final String CallingId;
  const cllingId({required this.CallingId});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(child: ZegoUIKitPrebuiltCall(appID: 1205379035,
      appSign: 'fe1e7fcc992c93ef405d505e275a4b99f02a158eb6bb3fc313b0652ac59a19e3',
      callID: CallingId,
      userID: userID,
      userName:"user_$userID" ,
      config: ZegoUIKitPrebuiltCallConfig.oneOnOneVoiceCall()
    ));
  }
}
```

i tried to read about the app size and asked chatgpt also but i didnt got any solution. i am looking forward for any other alternative also.

Comment: Android Studio has the Analyze App feature or you simply open the APK in a ZIP tool and check what's so large.

Comment: Did you run the app in debug or release mode? The size of the APK will be large in debug, profile and .aab mode. Additionally, when you build the app in release APK mode, you can decrease the size by using the `--split-per-abi` flag.